# Automatically derived sealed trait/ADT ordering in Scala

Tags: scala, generic-programming, shapeless

Is it possible to automatically derive order on a sealed trait family in Scala?

For instance, it would be nice to be able to do:

```
sealed trait Letters
case object A extends Letters
case object B extends Letters

(A < B) == True
```

This feels like something Shapeless may be able to handle, but I can't see if this currently exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the ordering to reflect the order of definition, not ordering by the names of the constructors.

This is no where near as fun as you might expect because `knownDirectSubclasses` on the [`ClassSymbol`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/scala-reflect/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Symbols$ClassSymbolApi) API returns a set of symbols, not an ordered sequence. I'm not an expert on scalac internals, but [according to Eugene Burmako](https://twitter.com/xeno_by/status/376830522686963712) (who is), the signature of `knownDirectSubclasses` just reflects what's happening in scalac.

I've been [complaining about this](https://twitter.com/travisbrown/status/376738546901471232) for years, by the way, and at various points I've tried things like [reading positions off the symbols](https://twitter.com/travisbrown/status/376787095580184576), but it doesn't really work.

Shapeless's generic machinery has to make a decision here, since it represents sealed traits as coproducts, which order their elements. In order to keep things deterministic, it uses the names of the constructors to order the cases:

```
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

sealed trait Letters
case object B extends Letters
case object A extends Letters

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined trait Letters
defined object B
defined object A

scala> shapeless.Generic[Letters]
res5: shapeless.Generic[Letters]{type Repr = shapeless.:+:[A.type,shapeless.:+:[B.type,shapeless.CNil]]} = anon$macro$45$1@71a11be4
```

If this is what you want, you're all set—just find a [good](https://github.com/fommil/shapeless-for-mortals) [tutorial](https://meta.plasm.us/posts/2015/11/08/type-classes-and-generic-derivation/) on Shapeless-powered generic derivation and work out the details. Unfortunately in most cases it's probably not what you want, though (`East`, `North`, `South`, `West`? `Blue`, `Green`, `Red`?), and what you want (definition ordering) doesn't seem to be reasonably possible.

Comment: The example in the question might only be illustrative, but on the face of it, alphabetical order (which is what shapeless provides) is exactly what's being asked for here ;-)

Comment: @MilesSabin Fair enough! That's pretty much the only example I can think of where alphabetical constructor names are what you want, though. :)

Answer (score 2):

When writing [Enumeratum](https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum), I came to the same conclusion as Travis, that `knownDirectSubclasses` isn't able to provide information about declaration order.

Still though, within the body of a given module, the AST is still ordered (type is `List[Tree]`), so that's how I managed to make [declaration-based ordering work](https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum/blob/master/macros/src/main/scala/enumeratum/EnumMacros.scala#L59) and offer an `indexOf` method. Once you have an ordered sequence of the sealed trait instances, getting an `Order` is fairly trivial.

Sorry, this isn't a Shapeless answer..